# Setting colors on a trimesh union mesh according to the original component meshes

Tags: python, trimesh

I'm working with the [trimesh](https://trimsh.org/) Python library, and I couldn't wrap my head around working with colors from reading the docs (a Spartan API reference) and examples. I'm not even sure if I'm setting the face colors right, if I can modify `mesh.visual.face_colors` directly or if I should make a `ColorVisuals`-type object.

But the main question is, can I set the color of different faces of a mesh *approximately* (I know there can be nasty edge cases) according to it being "overlapping" to faces in the original meshes I had before?

```
from shapely import Polygon
import trimesh

pts = ((100, 100), (400, 100), (400, 400), (100, 400))
hole = ((150, 150), (350, 150), (350, 350), (150, 350))
p = Polygon(pts, [hole])

mesh = trimesh.creation.extrude_polygon(p, 100)
other = mesh.copy()

other.apply_translation((150, 50, 50))
mesh = mesh.union(other)
# Silly idea (most faces wouldn't be the same) and it doesn't work, I get an error.
# other_v_set = set(other.vertices)
# colors = [([255, 0, 0] if set(mesh.vertices[v] for v in f).issubset(other_v_set)
#            else [0, 255, 0]) for f in mesh.faces]
# mesh.visual = trimesh.visual.ColorVisuals(mesh, colors)
mesh.show()
```

[image: mesh resulting from the union of two frame-like meshes, with text asking the main question about coloring the different parts]